# Flutter workmanager package does not execute tasks in when the device goes in idle or doze mode

Tags: android, flutter, android-workmanager, background-task, flutter-workmanager

I am using WorkManager package in Flutter to run code in background. The scheduled task runs perfectly when the mobile is not off or I am using phone. But as soon as the mobile enters idle or doze mode, all background tasks stops and when I again exit idle mode, background tasks start running. Why it is so? Is it something related to Android os restrictions.